# Pointers on writing a neovim plugin to execute a series of commands on a terminal and resize it to the appropriate size?

Tags: terminal, vim-plugin, neovim

When I'm coding in `nvim`, I find myself often wanting to open a job monitoring command line tool my company uses on the side. Basically I want to map a keybinding to the action :`open a neovim terminal window, run a sequence of commands, resize/rename/reposition the window`.

I think this should be easy to do, but I'm new to writing neovim plugins and find the API pretty confusing. I've tried Googling around, but it would be helpful if someone could point out useful functions or a link to a similar plugin on Github so I can look through the code (I think it's easiest to learn by example).

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

If keeping your workspace(windows size / opened files) arrangement
even after leaving vim is what you want, you do not need plugins for that.

### Option 1: Session

'Session' feature of vim (`:h session`) is what you're looking for.

`:mks! filename` to save current session to `filename`.
`:so filename` to load that session and restore window size / opened files.
If you launch vim with `vim -S filename`, it'll `:so filename` on startup.

The default value of `filename` is `Session.vim` on all 3 cases.

**TL;DR**

Given that working directory of your shell is already at the project directory,

- `:mks!` to save current workspace.
- Use `vim -S` to launch vim and automatically restore last workspace.

### Option 2: Job control

If you're on linux, you can use job control feature of the console.
Pressing `Ctrl+Z` will 'suspend' your current process - which in this case, vim.
Vim will be put in the background and you'll get your command prompt back.
After you're done with using command line tools,
run command `fg` to bring vim back to the foreground.

**TL;DR**

- `Ctrl+Z` to put vim in the background .
- `fg<Enter>` to bring vim back to foreground.

Comment: `vim -S` works find for Neovim as well, just do `nvim -S`.   
Also there is a Option 3, which is using terminal buffer.   
It's basically an embedded console inside vim.